# Python Regex matcher until two characters like a OR condition

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy, sql-parser

My question is quite simple 
I'm trying to come up with a RE to select any set of words or statement in between two characters. 
For example is the strings are something like this :

```
') as whatever '
```

and it can also look like

```
') as whatever\r\n'
```

So i need to extract **'whatever'** from this string.

The Regex I came up with is this :

```
\)\sas\s(.*?)\s
```

It works fine and extracts **'whatever'** but this will **only work for the first example not the second**. What should i do in case of the second statement

I'm basically looking for an **OR** condition kind of thing!

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `\s+` instead of `\s`? Then it matches one or more whitespace characters (which you need for `\r\n`)

Comment: It seems working, see https://regex101.com/r/34AFCE/1. `\s` matches `\r`, too (regex101 line endings have no `\r`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not very clear but maybe the regular expression syntax you are looking for might be something like this:

```
\)\sas\s(.*?)[\s | \r | \n]
```

basically telling after the string you are interested you can find a space or other characters.

EDIT
As example take the following code in Python2. The OR operator is '|' and I used it in the square brackets to catch the strings which have as subsequent character a space, '\r' a . or 'd'.

```
import re
a = ') as whatever '
b = ') as whatever\r\n'
c = ') as whatever.'
d = ') as whateverd'
a_res =  re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)[\s | \r | \n]', a)[0] #ending with     space, \r or new line char
b_res =  re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)[\s | \r | \n]', b)[0]
c_res =  re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)[\s | \r | \on | \.]', c)[0] #ending with space, \r new line char or .
d_res =  re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)[\s | \r | \on | \. | d]', d)[0] #ending with space, \r, new line char, . or d
print(a_res, len(a_res))
print(b_res, len(b_res))
print(c_res, len(c_res))
print(d_res, len(d_res))
```

Comment: I updated the question with an example. It works in python2. If it does not work please copy the error.

Answer (score 1):

It is working as you intended. Please check it

```
import re
a =') as whatever '
b=') as whatever\r\n'
print re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)\s', a)[0]
print re.findall(r'\)\sas\s(.*?)\s', b)[0]
```

This will output as

```
'whatever'
'whatever'
```